# Is there a way to iterate through the rows using the lambda function to add values from the a row to the following row?

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, data-science

**I have the following dataframe that shows the duration of a job taken by an employee as shown:**

| Date | ID number | Hour | Job duration |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 14/07/2022 | 1123 | 12 | 240 |
| 14/07/2022 | 1123 | 13 | 0 |
| 14/07/2022 | 1123 | 14 | 0 |
| 14/07/2022 | 1123 | 15 | 0 |
| 14/07/2022 | 1123 | 16 | 70 |
| 14/07/2022 | 1123 | 17 | 0 |

**I've iterated through the dataframe to "spread" the minutes along the hour using the following code:**

```
for i in df.index:
    if df["Job duration"][i] > 60:
        x = df["Job duration"][i] - 60
        df["Job duration"][i] = 60
        df["Job duration"][i+1] = df["Job duration"][i+1] + x
```

**This code works in a small dataset as shown below. In a large dataset however, this doesn't work and will take a long time computationally.**

| Date | ID number | Hour | Job duration |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 14/07/2022 | 1123 | 12 | 60 |
| 14/07/2022 | 1123 | 13 | 60 |
| 14/07/2022 | 1123 | 14 | 60 |
| 14/07/2022 | 1123 | 15 | 60 |
| 14/07/2022 | 1123 | 16 | 60 |
| 14/07/2022 | 1123 | 17 | 10 |

**Is there a method of using the lambda function in python to iterate through the rows of the "Job duration" column to speed the process? Thanks in advance.**

Comment: What should happen if the last row of your data is more than hour, e.g.: `['14/07/2022', 1123, 18, 70]`? I.e., we can't spread it to [i+1]. Should it remain 70 minutes in that case?

Comment: Thanks for your question. This is just a snippet of the dataset. The last few hours of the shift will have 0 usually as it is all recorded (job duration-wise) so it will all even out to 24 hours max.

Comment: I tried to find vectorized solution without any luck... Hope someone will advise on this option also

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how fast this solution is, but you may just give it a shot:

```
import pandas as pd

def update_series(series):
    copied = series.copy()
    shifted = series.sub(60).shift(1).fillna(0).clip(lower=0)
    while max(shifted) > 0:
        series.update(shifted[shifted > 0])
        series.update(copied[copied > 60])
        shifted = shifted.shift(1).sub(60).fillna(0).clip(lower=0)
    series[series > 60] = 60
    return series

df = pd.DataFrame({"ID": [1123, 1123, 1123, 1123, 1123, 1123, 1123, 1123, 1123],
                   "Job duration": [0,210,0,0,0,0,70,0,0]})
df["Job duration"] = update_series(df["Job duration"])
```